# How to redirect domain to new server?

Tags: domain, redirect

I've got a domain registered with a hosting company who I no longer wish to use. I'm happy for them to keep managing my domain, but I want my domain to point to my new (better) server which i've just bought and set up.

I know my new server's IP address and Nameservers,

What do I need to do in my domain management control panel to make it point to my new server?

- Change the "A" record to the new IP?
- Change the nameservers to my new hosts nameservers?

Is that it? Are there no other record on either server which need changing? I always get confused by who needs to do what when it comes to domains...

Thanks, 
Hugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy for your existing host to keep managing the domain, you don't even need to change the nameservers - just the A record. Change it to point to the IP of your new server and you're set.

Comment: o rly... That might help answer my next question.. If I do change nameservers, do my new hosts need to do anything to set it up? I did change one domain (both A and NS) and its not working...

Comment: If you change the name servers, it will transfer control of the domain DNS to your new host, but if the new host's name servers have no records for the domain you have transferred, you will still need to set these up somehow (control panel at your new host, most likely). Just transferring name servers will not automatically repoint the domain to your new IP.

Comment: ah - that'd be it then! Bugger. Shall have to contact the hosts and see if they'll do the deed for me. So to recap, moving domains to point at new servers really only needs you to change the A record.

Comment: So only change A, MX, leave nameservers alone?

Comment: Yes, if you're happy (as you say) to keep the domain managed by your old hosting company then that's the simplest way.

Comment: OK, all done - thats great thank you. I've got one more question though, who takes responsibility for adding mail server records? Do I need to add them into my plesk DNS settings, or do I do that with my existing host? Does pointing the A record transfer all responsibility to my new server?

Comment: No, the mail exchanger (MX) record is a separate record - you will need to add these in in as well (on whichever host's name servers are responsible for the domain).

Comment: heh, interesting looking at this 6 months on - seems so simple and day-to-day now...

Comment: Yep—that's the way of technology! Our kids will know things we'll never comprehend...